# Jquery inside a angular2 Typescript not working

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Hi Im using jquery inside angular 4 typescript . I tried with below two events to make table header fixed. But its not working.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table").tableHeadFixer({"head" : false, "left" : 1}); 
    });

}

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#table").tableHeadFixer({"head" : false, "left" : 1}); 
    });
 }
```

After rendered table, if i go to browser console execute below command

```
$("#table").tableHeadFixer({"head" : false, "left" : 1});
```

table header is get freezes now.

Please help on this.

Comment: First of all ?why are you using jquery. Never do it. what is that you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to make header and first row to be fixed. Is there any option to achieve this functionality?

Comment: what is the grid you are using ?

Comment: I'm using simple html table

Comment: because you call it several times

Comment: @RomanC I used in ngOnInit alone also tried with ngAfterViewInit alone. Both are not working

Comment: @PrabhuArumugam Can you create a plunker to demonstrate the error

Comment: I would suggest you to use [**prime-ng**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)'s data table

Answer (score 1):

Don't use jquery inside angular like that. If you need a good table library there are plenty of good choices designed for angular2-4:

```
ngx-datatable - https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/
ng2-table - https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table
wijmo - http://wijmo.com/angular2/
ag-Grid - https://www.ag-grid.com/
```

Comment: this must be a comment